# ngrx-router-store with previous route

Tags: angular, angular-routing, ngrx

I'm in a situation where I want to provide a proper navigation in my app using back buttons displayed on the screen, and not only the browser back button.

Now I'm using ngrx in general in my app. I've checked what kind of solution they might have provided for tracking the router, and of course they do provide one solution, the [router-store](https://ngrx.io/guide/router-store).

However, it looks like router-store only provides info about the current route and not the previous one.

So after a lot of searching I couldn't find any possible solution for this and I decided to implement my own router tracking state. It worked, but now I cannot use `routerLink` directive because it will not dispatch my action. And the whole state would be lost if the user entered a link directly in the URL! So it is not really the best solution.

Can I extend the router-store in some way to store the previous route data? Or can I use my own reducer to listen to router-store actions like `ROUTER_REQUEST` and `ROUTER_NAVIGATED`?